# OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework.GLFW Exception

Tags: macos, visual-studio, opengl, opentk

NSGL: The targeted version of macOS only supports forward-compatible core profile contexts for OpenGL 3.2 and above"

Hello everyone. When I try to run my Visual Studio Code included with OpenTK my MacBook shows me this error.